# Xact Visual Studio 2013

Tags: xna-4.0

Trying to insert music into an xna project the play it while the game  is running. I am using VS 2013 and I am reading in a book where if you insert an xap file then compile, it will turn into a xgs and xsb. Only problem when I compile I dont see these files generate so my code gives an error.

The error is about that it cannot find the file on the lines below.

```
audioEngine = new AudioEngine(@"Content/Audio/GameAudio.xgs");
waveBank = new WaveBank(audioEngine, @"Content\Audio\Wave Bank.xwb");
```

I have an game I downloaded with sounds (example code) made in vs 2010 and it works just fine and is set up just the same as above.

```
soundBank = new SoundBank(audioEngine, @"Content\Audio\Sound Bank.xsb");
```

Trying to figure out how to make these .xgs and xwb files in 2013.